# Task Names for Gantt Chart in Vega-lite

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, vega-lite, vega, deneb

Hello I'm trying to create a Gantt Chart Visual in Vega Lite and i want to add the task names next the projekt name as extra column and that certain milestones with typ=4 are displayed with a different shape.

The data looks like the following:

| USERPOS | PROJEKT_NAME | PLANSTART | PLANENDE | typ | User_pos_ordering | Project_pos_name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Projekt 1 | 24.06.2022 | 24.06.2023 | 1 | 1 | Task 1 |
| 2 | Projekt 1 | 13.02.2023 | 19.02.2023 | 2 | 2 | Task 2 |
| 2.1 | Projekt 1 | 15.02.2023 | 16.02.2023 | 3 | 2 | Task 3 |
| 2.1.1 | Projekt 1 | 16.02.2023 | 17.02.2023 | 3 | 2 | Task 4 |
| 2.1.1.1 | Projekt 1 | 16.02.2023 | 23.02.2023 | 4 | 2 | Task 5 |

The json code i already have is:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"name": "dataset"},
  "height": {"step": 15},
  "layer": [
    {
      "layer": [
        {
          "params": [
            {
              "name": "grid",
              "select": "interval",
              "bind": "scales"
            }
          ],
          "mark": {
            
            "type": "bar",
            "cornerRadius": 15

          },
          "encoding": {
            "color": {"field": "typ"}
          }
        },
        {
          "mark": {
            "type": "text",
            "align": "right"
          },
          "encoding": {
            "text": {
              "field": "USERPOS"
            },
            "color": {
              "value": "#000000"
            }
          }
        }
        
      ],
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "field": "PLANSTART",
          "type": "temporal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Date",
            "grid": true,
            "gridColor": "black",
            "gridDash": [4, 4],
            "gridOpacity": {
              "condition": {
                "test": {
                  "field": "value",
                  "timeUnit": "month",
                  "equal": 1
                },
                "value": 1
              },
              "value": 0
            },
            "format": "%b%y"
          }
        },
        "y": {
          "field": "PROJEKT_Name",
          "type": "nominal",
          "axis": {
            "title": "Project Name",
            "grid": true,
            "tickBand": "extent"
          }
        },
        "x2": {"field": "PLANENDE"},
        "yOffset": {
          "field": "project_pos_name",
          "sort": {"field": "User_pos_ordering", "order":"ascending"}
        },
        "color": {"field": "typ"}
      }
    },
    {
      "transform": [
        {
          "calculate": "now()",
          "as": "now_field"
        }
      ],
      "mark": {
        "type": "rule",
        "color": "green",
        "size": 2
      },
      "encoding": {
        "x": {
          "sort": {"field": "PLANSTART"},
          "field": "now_field",
          "type": "temporal"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

With this specification it looks like this:

[image: Current Version]

And want i want to achieve is something like this:

[image: Desired Version]

I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: What you want to do isn't possible with your current approach. You have used the yOffset channel for your tasks but the axis is only aware of the PROJEKT_NAME field in the datum.value of the axis. There are hacks to get this working but I wouldn't recommend them. In case you're interested, there is a gantt chart written in Vega here by me which might be useful. https://github.com/PBI-David/Deneb-Showcase

Comment: Yes I'm aware of your very beautiful looking gantt-chart, however I do struggle a lot to apply the changes i want in your version: coloring of subtasks based on a column and a montly timeline. But if could tell me a way how and where to edit i will certainly use your version

Comment: You can achieve something similar in VL but I would not use the yOffset channel to do this and would instead try and think of a different approach.

Comment: Ibendlin converted my chart into a monthly version here: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Desktop/Deneb-David-Bacci-Gantt-Chart-How-to-modify-daily-timeline-to/td-p/3488350

Comment: Perfectly is there a way to also achieve the coloring of tasks based on a specific column?

Comment: Yes, I'll add a full answer so I can share the details. Please don't forget to mark as solved.

Comment: Yes i will certainly do so. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

[New link](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

**EDIT END**

Add a new scale:

```
   {
  "name": "tFill",
  "type": "ordinal",
  "range": {"scheme":"category10"},
  "domain": {"data": "input", "field": "task"}
}
```

Use the new scale in these two places:

```
              "fill": {
                "signal": "item.mark.group.datum.task",
                "scale": "tFill"
              },
              "stroke": {
                "signal": "item.mark.group.datum.task",
                "scale": "tFill"
              },


          "fill": {"field": "task", "scale": "tFill"},
          "stroke": {"field": "task", "scale": "tFill"},
```

[Full spec](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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) (too big for SO so link only):

[image]

Comment: Work perfect thank you!

Maybe 2 small follow-up question: what exactly do i have to remove such that i dont' have a progress bar?
If 2 phases have the same naming but are in different projects the dates and names get plotted above each other, is there way to mitigate this?

Comment: Do you want the task or phase progress bars removed? Or both? They are labelled in the spec and can just be deleted. The ordering of the tasks and phases is quite intricate - phase is top level and task is sub level. What exactly is the issue you're seeing?

Comment: It just occurs on the columns of the left. If i have project 1 with the name task 1 name and project 2 also with task 1, the columns on left for project 1 will display the name "task 1" twice, start and end in an overlapping fashion and don't print it for project 2

Comment: Are you able to post a spec in the online editor with the issue. The code is quite intricate and it has been a while since I looked at it.

Comment: Maybe ask a new question with all the details.

Comment: It's very easy to replicate: just name a task the same way in 2 phases in your spec and you see the overlapping

Comment: I see the problem. Unfortunately, this isn't easy to fix with the way I have done the transforms and would take me quite a while to unpick. However, if you add a space to the duplicate task names to ensure they are always unique, this problem can be avoided. This can be done in a measure so you don't have to change your actual data. Not ideal but to fix it properly would take me a while and this was only ever intended as a showcase of what is possible.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how this can be done easily in Vega with a new link.

Comment: The new link has requirements gathering repeated twice for instance.